# Rails suddenly gives routes error when using form with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I've made a button which when clicked creates a `shopping_cart_item` and then redirects to the same page showing a button to delete this same `shopping_cart_item`. This al works fine. When I try to use ajax the remove from cart button works fine but all of a sudden when I click the add to cart button I get the following error:

```
Started POST "/shopping_cart_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-26 17:04:04 +0100
Processing by ListsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "course_id"=>"10", "listtype"=>"shopping_cart_items"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '7c8d45b38c4739022112db6ec137f31f60fada60' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "shopping_cart_items" ("course_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["course_id", 10], ["created_at", Sun, 26 Jan 2014 16:04:04 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 26 Jan 2014 16:04:04 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered browse_courses/_uncart.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered lists/create.js.erb (3.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :listtype=>"shopping_cart_items", :controller=>"lists"}):
    1: <%= form_tag({:controller => 'lists', :action => 'destroy', listtype: 'shopping_cart_items'}, method: 'delete', remote: true) do %>
    2:   <div><%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, params[:id] %></div>
    3: 
    4:   <%= button_tag(name: nil, class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
  app/views/browse_courses/_uncart.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_browse_courses__uncart_html_erb__2389702037921073695_70286519726020'
  app/views/lists/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_lists_create_js_erb___3945578670069953364_70286487293260'
  app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:6:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/Jaap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mprog1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/Jaap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mprog1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/Jaap/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mprog1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (15.6ms)
```

The form used to add an item to the cart

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'lists', :action => 'create', listtype: 'shopping_cart_items'}, method: 'post', remote: true) do %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, params[:id] %></div>

  <%= button_tag(name: nil, class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
    add to cart
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

the form used to remove an item from the cart

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'lists', :action => 'destroy', listtype: 'shopping_cart_items'}, method: 'delete', remote: true) do %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, params[:id] %></div>

  <%= button_tag(name: nil, class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
        deletings
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My routes for the lists controller:

```
 listtype_regexp = Regexp.new([:shopping_cart_items, :currently_taking_items, :recently_viewed_items].join("|"))
 resources :lists, only: [:create, :destroy], path: ':listtype', constraints: { listtype: listtype_regexp }
```

the lists controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController


  def create
    addToList!(params[:course_id], current_user.shopping_cart_items)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to controller: 'browse_courses', action: 'show', type: 'courses', id: params[:course_id] }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    removeFromList!(params[:course_id], current_user.shopping_cart_items)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to controller: 'browse_courses', action: 'show', type: 'courses', id: params[:course_id] }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#cart_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('browse_courses/uncart')) %>")
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#cart_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('browse_courses/cart')) %>")
```

rake routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
         users GET    /users(.:format)         users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)         users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)     users#new
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)     users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)     users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)     users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)     users#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)      sessions#create
   new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)  sessions#new
       session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)  sessions#destroy
         lists POST   /:listtype(.:format)     lists#create {:listtype=>/shopping_cart_items|currently_taking_items|recently_viewed_items/}
          list DELETE /:listtype/:id(.:format) lists#destroy {:listtype=>/shopping_cart_items|currently_taking_items|recently_viewed_items/}
browse_courses GET    /:type(.:format)         browse_courses#index {:type=>/courses|institutes|programmes|staff/}
 browse_course GET    /:type/:id(.:format)     browse_courses#show {:type=>/courses|institutes|programmes|staff/}
          root GET    /                        static_pages#home
        signup GET    /signup(.:format)        users#new
        signin GET    /signin(.:format)        sessions#new
       signout DELETE /signout(.:format)       sessions#destroy
          help GET    /help(.:format)          static_pages#help
         about GET    /about(.:format)         static_pages#about
       contact GET    /contact(.:format)       static_pages#contact
```

Comment: Am I correct in the assumption, that the file you described as "The form used to add an item to the cart" is browse_courses/cart?

Comment: Further: Is the internal server error part of the post request on "/shopping_cart_items"? And have you tried 'rake routes' to see what routes are actually there?

Comment: Yes that is correct! I don't exactly know what you mean by: 'Is the internal server error part of the post request on "/shopping_cart_items"' and i did run 'rake routes' see my edit above

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the problem :) The error appears when you add ajax to the application and click the add to cart button, right?

Comment: Can you also post the page without AJAX controls? :)